# Fragment OutOfMemory

Tags: android, bitmap, android-fragments, android-viewpager, out-of-memory

How can I efficiently recycle large images in Fragments (more precisely, in **ViewPager**)?

In **onDestroyView()** I recycle the bitmap by doing bitmap.recycle(), but first I store the path to the in the **Bundle** in **onSaveInstanceState**. I read thousands questions and threads about case when onSaveInstanceState is not called. However, **FragementStatePagerAdapter** calls **destroyView()** therefore it deallocates the resources associated to the fragment.

If I prevent the FragmentStatePagerAdapter from calling **super.destroyView()** I will keep the UI of the Fragment untouched, I'm aware of it.

What I want to achieve is to do **.recycle()** when the fragment is destroyed, save the path to the bitmap in the onSaveInstanceState and then reuse the path to create new bitmap when **onCreateView()** is called and then put the same bitmap in the **ImageView** of the Fragment UI.

I use Google's guide for efficiently  loading/sampling bitmaps before I set them to the ImageView.

Any pointers would be great!

Answer (score 0):

Think other way. Create Bitmap manager that will use LruCache and be accessable to all your fragments/views you use in the pager. This way you always have up-to-date bitmaps in memory and limited amount of them not to get OutOfMemory exception.